# Java: Wrapping objects in some type of collection to store duplicates in a set

Tags: java, duplicates, set

I want to make a set of some type of collection (not sure which one yet) as a way of "storing duplicates" in a set. For example if I wanted to add the integer 5 with 39 additional copies I could put it into an arraylist at index 39. Thus if I were to get the size of the arraylist, I would know how many copies of 5 existed within the set.

There are a few other ways I could implement this but I have yet to decide on one. The main issue I'm having with implementing this is that I'm not sure how I can "dynamically" make arraylists (or whatever collection I may end up using) so that whenever someone were to call `mySet.add(object)`, the object is first inserted into a unique arraylist then into the set itself.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how I could approach this?

EDIT:

Sorry I should have been more clear in my question. The point of the code that I'm writing is that we have a set-like collection that allows duplicates. And yes some of the associated methods will be re-written/will have to be re-written. Also my code should be written under the assumption that we do not know what type of object is being inserted(only one data type per set though) nor how many instances of the same object will be added nor how many different unique objects will be added.

Comment: **Why** not use an `ArrayList<Integer>`? A `Set` shouldn't have duplicates.

Comment: Sometimes it can be clearer what you're asking for if you define the operations that your collection can support.  What's the contract of `add`?  What other operations are required?  Offhand this sounds like a [`Multiset<T>`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset), which is basically a specialization for `Map<T, Integer>`.

Comment: Why not simply store a count of the number of times an object occurs?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I was thinking of doing that but wouldnt that be hard to do with a set, since the order you add objects into a set dont matter, iteration results in a random output. Thus how would I know which count belonged to which object. I was thinking of writing an inner class of some sorts which basically creates a new object which consists of a "data" variable and a "count" variable

Answer (score 4):

I would rather go for using a `Map` like

```
HashMap list <Object, Integer>
```

where Object is the Object that you want to count and `Integer` is the count

Comment: Edited Question to add more info... Sorry for not making this clear at first but the i'm writing code to make a set-like collection that allows duplicates.

Comment: What is the purpose of having duplicates?

Comment: Sorry if its still unclear but there is no purpose other than simply the objective of my code is to make a set-like collection which allows duplicates.

Comment: As per Elliot's original comment, *A Set shouldn't have duplicates*  So you are trying to use an Object for the wrong purpose.  The correct Object to use is a `Map`

Comment: Again sorry if its still unclear but I am making a "set-like" collection. I'm not using an actual set and trying to make a way to store duplicates. In addition most of the methods associated with the set collection will be rewritten to accommodate this "set-like" colleciton.

Answer (score 1):

You could try guava's MultiSet, I think it's what you want.

It can store the count of each object. What you need to do is just 
    multiSet.put(object); 
And if it is put for the first time, like you said, a new list will be created, or its count will added by one.

Comment: Edited Question to add more info... Sorry for not making this clear at first but the i'm writing code to make a set-like collection that allows duplicates.

Comment: You mean you want to store more than one type of object, and each kind may also duplicate?

Comment: Sorry if its still unclear but only one type of object will be allowed in this set. And for that object type, there can be duplicates for any of the objects inserted into this set.

Comment: Then what's wrong with MultiSet<T> ? I really think it's just what you want.  See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Comment: I'm sorry if its still unclear but using a multiset in this scenario wouldnt be acceptable for me. I am making a "set-like" collection (not using an actual set) where the methods usually associated with the set collection will be rewritten to reflect this "set-like" collection which allows duplicates.